# Add text from inside of a file above a line match in another file

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file **File1.txt** that contains the following:

```
abc
def
ghi
```

I have another file **File2.txt** that contains the following:

```
123
456
789
```

I would like to add the contents of file 1 above 789 to give:

```
123
456
abc
def
ghi
789
```

Ultimately using sed or awk.
I tried a workaround where I used:

```
file1="$(cat File1.txt)"
sed -i "/^789/i $file1 " File2.txt
```

However this does not work as intended. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you for your expertise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute `cat` with GNU sed:

```
sed '/^789$/e cat file1' file2
```

Output:

```
123
456
abc
def
ghi
789
```

Answer (score 0):

With any awk in any shell on every UNIX box for any value of `789`:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{new=new $0 ORS; next} $0=="789"{printf "%s", new} 1' file1 file2
123
456
abc
def
ghi
789
```

The only caveat is that `file1` can't be so massive that it doesn't fit in memory.